# Copiar linhas e colar com base num valor em uma célula excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Gostaria de saber como posso copiar um conjunto de linhas. Por exemplo, linha 1 até 5 e colar nas linhas 10 a 15. Essa acção seria feita com o valor 1 em outra outra folha e na célula A1.

Tenho um botão com VBA para fazer isso, mas queria fazer automaticamente quando o valor da célula é "28" ou "29".

Estes são os códigos que tenho em botão. Um adiciona e o outro remove as linhas.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Fevereiro").Rows("5:9").Copy (Sheets("Fevereiro").Rows("11:15"))

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Worksheets("Fevereiro").Rows("11:15").Delete

End Sub
```

Isto é para tentar fazer o seguinte:
O mês de fevereiro ora tem 28 dias ou 29. 
Tenho uma fórmula `FIMMÊS` para me dar o dia exacto se o mês termina a 28 ou 29 conforme o ano.

Se de um ano para o outro o mês tiver mais um dia, o VBA adiciona um certo número de linhas na folha "Fevereiro" (logo abaixo da última linha preenchida) ou remove se no ano seguinte só tiver 28 novamente.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais simples de verificar a quantidade de dias em um mês é a seguinte:

```
Ano = 2018
Mes = 2
DiasNoMes = Day(DateSerial(Ano, Mes + 1, 0))
MsgBox DiasNoMes
```

Que retorna o número 28, ou seja, o mês de Fevereiro de 2018 possui 28 dias.

Então uma lógica condicional `if` pode ser criada com:

```
If DiasNoMes = 28 Then
    Sheets("Fevereiro").Rows("5:9").Copy (Sheets("Fevereiro").Rows("11:15"))
ElseIf DiasNoMes = 29 Then
    Worksheets("Fevereiro").Rows("11:15").Delete
End If
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não estou a conseguir meter esse exemplo em prática. Não percebo muito de vba. o primeiro código coloco onde? O código If é para meter entre algo?